# NCURSES - missprinting new lines when printing in tty mode

Tags: c, ncurses

I have this program:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

SCREEN * sstderr;
SCREEN * sstdout;

int main() {
    sstderr = newterm(NULL, stderr, NULL);
    noecho();
    sstdout = newterm(NULL, stdout, stdin);
    set_term(sstdout);

    addstr("PRESS A KEY");
    getch();
    def_prog_mode();
    endwin();

    system("ls -l");

    getchar();
    reset_prog_mode();
    refresh();
    addstr("Press another key");
    getch();
    set_term(sstdout);
    endwin();
    set_term(sstderr);
    endwin();
}
```

every line that is in the output of the 'ls -l' command gets missprinted like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    4096 Feb 11 09:22 bin
                        drwxr-xr-x   3 root root    4096 Mar  6  2016 boot
                                                drwxr-xr-x  18 root root    3380 Feb 23 00:12 dev
                                                                        drwxr-xr-x 113 root root   12288 Apr 25 10:45 etc
...
```

I tried using def_shell_mode() just before the `initscr()` line (or newterm() in my case), and reset_shell_mode() just before `system("ls -l");` but the problem persists.
the only way I can kind of fix this is using

```
system("reset");
```

just before the `system("ls -l");` line.

Anyone know what the real problem is, and how I can fix it without that "reset" call?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside from noticing that you're using **getchar** (not a curses function), a simple program containing that fragment works as intended.  Perhaps a more complete example would help.  Also, if you're using Cygwin, it's notorious for staircasing problems.

Comment: Yes, I do use getchar there because I am suppose to be out of curses mode (in tty mode until reset_prog_mode() instruction)..

Comment: Updated program source code to a complete program that presents the described behaviour..

Comment: I am not familiar with suspending/resuming ncurses, but I suspect the output of `ls` is sized for the ncurses character and terminal-width, causing the lines to be longer than can be displayed within the terminal in "tty" mode and the subsequent wrapping of the ends of each of the lines which is seen as the horizontal displacement with each following line. (this is just an educated guess which I suspect is close to what is happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program initializes the same terminal into curses mode twice.  But the first time it sets the terminal into raw mode starting from cooked mode.  The second time it is already in raw mode.  It doesn't matter (much) that those are separate streams, but that they're connected to the same terminal driver.

Having initialized the second screen (for standard output), and then doing a "restore", nothing happens because it restores to raw mode.

You could "fix" it by switching back to the standard-error screen before doing `endwin`.  Offhand, you'd have problems copying the shell-mode terminal settings from one screen to another.